# How to simulate an SMTP server?

Tags: php, node.js, email, smtp, exim

I am trying to simulate an SMTP server, to execute some scripts when sending an email via SMTP relay.

I have been using exim, but could not find a way to use my own code. I believe it is possible to simulate an SMTP server using Node JS but could not find any resource.

So I need some sort of code that listens to the port 25, 465 or 587 or any other, and execute my code everytime a user connects to my smtp server. Is it possible?

I would appreciate any help.

Best regards

Comment: You want to send an email via your nodejs app?

Comment: Of course you can implement your own SMTP implementation, just follow the RFC 5321: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321.
But i think it would be much easier to execute an external script you provide within exim: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/execute-script-on-receive-email-with-exim

Comment: If you absolutely want to go this route, there are [plenty of tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+socket+server+tutorial) that teach you how to build a socket server in nodejs and have it listen on a specific port.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Basically lets say i have a php mailer script, within the options i have smtp.myserver.com, i need an app on that subdomain to process the incoming connection, reads the email content and parameters, then i send the email somehow, but within the process i will lets say count 1 email sent.  I have been trying this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/smtp-server using the subdomain smtp.mydomain.com and listening on port 2525 but i always get connection refused.

Comment: Are you sure the smtp-server is running? Can you connect to it using telnet? You configured php.ini to use the port 2525 instead of the default?

Comment: It worked after i disabled the firewall, now i am able to connect, but it works only if TLS is disabled, but i need authentication, I hace set the key and crt but it does not connect now, it only connects if the authentication is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could accomplish this task using smtp-server on node.js, working perfectly!